# Dereferencing upcasted member function pointers

Tags: c++

Let's say I have 2 classes `Instrument` and `Brass`, where `Brass` is derived from `Instrument`:

```
class Instrument
{
protected:
 std::string _sound;
public:
 Instrument(std::string sound) : _sound(sound) {}
 virtual void play() { std::cout << _sound << std::endl; }
};

class Brass : public Instrument
{
private:
 std::string _pitchShifter;
public:
 Brass(std::string pitchShifter) : Instrument("braaaaaa"), _pitchShifter(pitchShifter)
 {}

 void printPitchShifter() { std::cout << _pitchShifter << std::endl; }
}
```

For some crazy reason I have a pointer to a member function of Instrument:

```
typedef void(Instrument::*instrumentVoidFunc)() //declaring member function pointers is too damn confusing
instrumentVoidFunc instrumentAction;
```

Now obviously, this will work, with well-defined behaviour:

```
Instrument soundMaker("bang!");
instrumentAction = &Instrument::play;
(soundMaker.*instrumentAction)();
```

And the output should be `bang!`.

But I can also make `instrumentAction` point to a Brass member function **not** present in `Instrument` by upcasting it, like so:

```
instrumentAction = static_cast<instrumentVoidFunc>(&Brass::printPitchShifter);
```

My understanding is (or was, anyway) that upcasting the member function pointer should destroy any ability for it to refer to derived class functions that aren't already present in the base class. However:

```
Brass trumpet("valves");
(trumpet.*instrumentAction)();
```

...prints out `valves` just as if I had called the function on the derived class normally. So apparently upcasting a derived class function pointer does not affect what happens when it is dereferenced on a derived class (though dereferencing it on a base class gives undefined behaviour).

How exactly does the compiler make this possible?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, just wanted to say that C++ function pointers are horrible.

Comment: In general, be careful not to conflate empirical results with correct behaviour. C++ in particular has many different kinds of undefined (or implementation defined) behaviour that will cause seemingly-correct stuff to happen from incorrect code  (often this is pure coincidence).

Comment: it sounds like you are implementing a vtable manually?

Comment: @(guy with the hex name) thanks, just fixed that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although function pointer casts are possible, calling a function through a function type which doesn't match the original type is undefined behavior. The reason function pointer casts are allowed is to support casting to and storing a common type but recovering the correct by casting the function pointer back before calling it. The basic background for this restriction is that even compatible pointers may require adjustment upon use. Hiding the correct signature would imply a suitable trampoline to exist (i.e., the function pointer would need to have additional state).

Comment: I imagine even method pointer casts that round-trip back to the original type still have to be done carefully, since the pointers may not all be the same size.